# fputcsv appends 'null' at end of file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, null, export-to-csv

I am trying to export some data as csv using the following code but it appends an unwanted 'null' at file end.

```
$array = array();
$fileName = 'test.csv';
$array[0] = ['Name','Email'];
$array[1] = ['Test','test@email.com'];
$fileObj = new FileStream();
$fileObj->array_to_csv_download($array,$fileName);
```

array_to_csv_download code -

```
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    foreach ($array as $line) {
        $this -> logObj -> LogError(" CSV ".json_encode($line));
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
    fseek($f, 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    fpassthru($f);
```

Output -

```
Name,Email
Test,test@email.com
null
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is FileStream's array_to_csv_download() code? and what's the content of `test.csv`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry I missed that. Please check now.

Comment: Apparently you are missing the fact that iterators (fpassthru or any other) return null as they reach the end of the file (eof). There is no "null character" at the eof. This is the way you can determine the eof using 'while not null' statement.

Answer (score 1):

How about generating CSV directly? Works for me.

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
foreach($array as $fields) {
  echo implode(",", $fields)."\n";
}
```

Comment: This also appends a null.